# Custom quicktags not working after Wordpress 6.0

Tags: quicktag

Custom quicktags not working after Wordpress 6.0

wp 5.8.x/5.9.x: working --
wp 6.0: not working

Buttons are not showing here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUXyV.jpg

Console error: Uncaught ReferenceError: QTags is not defined

I am using this code.

```
    function my_quicktags() {

    if ( wp_script_is( 'quicktags' ) ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    QTags.addButton( 'eg_php', 'PHP', '<pre><code class=\"language-php\">', '</code></pre>', 'p', 'PHP Code', 200 );
    QTags.addButton( 'eg_css', 'CSS', '<pre><code class=\"language-css\">', '</code></pre>', 'q', 'CSS Code', 201 );
    QTags.addButton( 'eg_html', 'HTML', '<pre><code class=\"language-html\">', '</code></pre>', 'r', 'HTML Code', 202 );
    QTags.addButton( 'eg_callback', 'CSS div', css_callback );

    function css_callback(){
        var css_class = prompt( 'Class name:', '' );

        if ( css_class && css_class !== '' ) {
            QTags.insertContent('<div class="' + css_class +'"></div>');
        }
    }
    </script>
    <?php
    }

}
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'my_quicktags' );
```

Comment: What’s not working? Are the buttons not working? Or do they not appear? Are there any errors in the console? Please elaborate.

Comment: can you be more specific? E.g. they're added but the buttons do nothing? Or there's a JS error in the console? Where are you trying to use these? Is there a particular screen you're trying to use this on? Have you confirmed your code runs and that it isn't broken by an error somewhere else in the browsers dev console?

Comment: I tested out `QTags.addButton( 'eg_php', 'PHP', '<pre><code class=\"language-php\">', '</code></pre>', 'p', 'PHP Code', 200 );` in WP 6.0 and it worked fine, I notice though, that rather than adding an inline script to `quicktags`, you're using `wp_script_is` and then manually writing out a script tag, which is highly unusual and non-standard. Are you sure that `if ( wp_script_is( 'quicktags' ) ) {` actually works as intended? Was there a particular reason you chose to write it this way? I suspect this has always been broken but it worked out of luck

Comment: Buttons are not showing here: https://imgur.com/a/T05o0WX
Console error: Uncaught ReferenceError: QTags is not defined

Comment: @TomJNowell The `wp_script_is()` usage is shown in the [Developer Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/quicktags/), so I can see where @Dominator0 would get that code from. @Nick R's answer below suggests using a more modern example from the Codex. I suspect the Developer Docs should be updated to include that "more modern example" as well.

Comment: @PatJ ticket opened to fix it at https://github.com/WordPress/Documentation-Issue-Tracker/issues/357

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by using the ep_enqueue_script aproach shown here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Quicktags_API listed under "A more modern example".

It's the same thing that Tom mentions. Instead of using 'admin_print_fotter_scripts' to write an inline script on the page, the example shows putting the Qtags javascript in a separate JS file, and loading it with 'admin_enqueue_scripts' as the action and calling wp_enqueue_script.

The Quicktags_API link above shows both methods, but the inline script method stoped working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Found a fix.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
           window.onload=function(){ 


    }
</script>
```

make sure the JS loads after the page fully loads this will allow the qtags js to work. Had the same issue as you right after I updated to 6.0. This fixed it for me.

Comment: For me this is the best solution.

Comment: I can confirm that simply adding the window.onload=function() worked for me to, it restored my custom quick tag buttons, I will post a fuller example below in case anyone else needs a bit more help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wp_add_inline_script` to add more quicktags, ensuring it only runs when `quicktags` is used, and runs after it's loaded:

```php
function add_quicktag_paragraph() {
    wp_add_inline_script(
        'quicktags',
        "QTags.addButton( 'eg_paragraph', 'p', '<p>', '</p>', 'p',     'Paragraph tag', 1 );"
);
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_quicktag_paragraph' );
```

Here the second parameter of `wp_add_inline_script` gets put into a `<script>` tag by WordPress, and it places it so that it shows *after* quicktags is loaded, not before. I've places a single line of code in my example but you could insert multiple lines instead.

This solves several problems the original snippet in the handbook had:

- it works on non-admin pages that use quicktags
- it always runs the code *after* quicktags is loaded, not before.
- no hardcoded script tags
- it's possible to filter and process this because of `wp_add_inline_script`
- if a plugin removes the quicktags code then this will not show and break

---

Another alternative is to write a JS file with your quicktags additions, and enqueue it, declaring quicktags as a dependency. This ensures it is always loaded in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks but can you post an example using <script type="text/javascript"> ... </script> ?

Comment: @Dominator0 that would involve completely destroying my answer and rewriting it using something that runs into your original problem, hardcoded `script` tags aren't necessary here, but also `wp_add_inline_script` is creating those script tags for you, the second parameter to `wp_add_inline_script` is what's going to go inside the script tags. In my example i have a single line of javascript but you could put _hundreds_ of lines of javascript.

Comment: e.g. `wp_add_inline_script( 'quicktags', 'your javascript goes here' );`

Answer (score 1):

Another fix..

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      QTags.addButton( 'test', 'Test', '<test>', '</test>', 'test' );
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me ([more info](https://perishablepress.com/wordpress-fix-error-qtags-not-defined/))

My QTags:

```
QTags.addButton('codelights', 'CodeLights', btnAction);
```

I edit to:

```
window.onload = function() {
    QTags.addButton('codelights', 'CodeLights', btnAction);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my custom quicktags I use in the Classic Editor (Text tab) disappeared after updating to 6.0+ and after much research I can confirm that the old code DOES still work with the addition of a single line of script (a window event) as suggested above by @kegnum and @Dominator0 (thanks!).

HERE is the full code snippet in case anyone needs it, be sure to modify this to suit your OWN needs, here I am adding some H tags:

```
// add more buttons to the html editor
function twe_add_quicktags() {
if (wp_script_is('quicktags')){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
QTags.addButton( 'eg_heading_3', 'h3', '<h3>', '</h3>', 'h3', 'Heading 3 tag', 1 );
QTags.addButton( 'eg_heading_4', 'h4', '<h4>', '</h4>', 'h4', 'Heading 4 tag', 1 );
QTags.addButton( 'eg_heading_5', 'h5', '<h5>', '</h5>', 'h5', 'Heading 5 tag', 1 );
});
</script>
<?php
}
}
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'twe_add_quicktags' );
```

I know there are several other methods, but this is a very simple one and it does the trick.